# Pass selected value to other component html

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am not much familiar with Angular . I have a code where I am inputting some values using dropdown select

**html 1:-**

```
<angular-material-filter-dropdown 
            [dropdownList]="['Solid', 'Liquid', 'Gas']" 
            (selected)="triggerStateSelect($event)">
</angular-material-filter-dropdown>
```

**Component 1:-**

```
triggerStateSelect(event) {
    console.log('state select  ', event);
  }
```

Here `event` stores the value.

**HTML 2:-**

```
<div class="title-container">
    <p class="title">
        {{}} -Dashboard
    </p>
</div>
```

Now I want to pass selected value to a different component and also to display the selected in HTML 
 Whenever a value is selected , the second component must get the value and shows the  value. Also when nothing is selected the second component must not show any previous selected value. It must get cleared.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: how's the situation? is first component a child of second component? are they sharing parent? or are they just separated?

Comment: @MajidNayyeri they are in separate modules

Answer (score 2):

You could use a service which provides you the Information with Observables. You create a service.ts file in which you declare your observable and observer. Everytime a value is selected you simply .next(value) in your service and then subscribe to it in the .ts file where you .html file is. Here is a good explanation on how to use Observables. I hope it helps
https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-creating-and-subscribing-to-observables-in-angular-426dbf0b04a3

Answer (score 1):

If they have parent-child relationship you can interact via input
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

If not, you can achieve it via service:

**Create Service:**

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SelectStateService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();
    triggerStateSelect() {
        this.subject.next();
    }
    onStateSelect(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

**Component 1:**

```
constractor(private selectStateService : SelectStateService ){}
triggerStateSelect(event){
  this.myService.triggerStateSelect(event);
 }
```

**Component 2:**

```
constractor(private selectStateService: SelectStateService){}
state;
this.$subscription = this.selectStateService.onStateSelect().subscribe((event) => {
    this.state = event;
    }
 );
ngOnDestroy() {
      this.$subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

**Html 2:**

```
<div class="title-container">
    <p class="title">
        {{state}} -Dashboard
    </p>
</div>
```

documentation:

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: So from where do I need to put that observable code ? I am still little confuse about it. Can you edit according to my code ? Not much familiar with rxjs

Comment: I changed it, you need to create angular service and it shares the observable for the components.

Comment: Hi am now able to pass using service . But how will I clear the event value when I remove the drop down selection so that the dynamic binding on second HTML aslo gets cleared ?

Comment: you can pass null: this.myService.triggerStateSelect(null)